# Как запихнуть в div

Tags: javascript

код:`https://codepen.io/xqzmy-afk/pen/ZEpBmJo`

```
function showNotification({top = 0, right = 0, className, html}) {
      let notification = document.createElement('div');
      notification.className = "notification";
      if (className) {
        notification.classList.add(className);
      }
      notification.innerHTML = html;
      document.body.append(notification);
      setTimeout(() => notification.remove(), 1500);
    }
    let i = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      showNotification({
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        html: 'Секунд прошло:' +  i++ + 'секунд',
        className: "welcome"
      });
    }, 2000);
      showNotification({
  top: 10, // 10px от верхней границы окна (по умолчанию 0px)
  left: 10, // 10px от правого края окна (по умолчанию 0px)
  html: 'Секунд прошло:', // HTML-уведомление
  className: "welcome" // дополнительный класс для div (необязательно)
});
```

Не понимаю как запихнуть div(notification) в div(в js) чтоб с помощью гридов отцентрировать по центру

Comment: `document.body.append(notification);` - ты уже запихиваешь в `body`, замени его на твой div и все. Про гриды непонятно, так как в коде они нигде не используются

Comment: не понял.Мне нужно чтоб было:<div><div class="notification"></div></div>.

Comment: что мешает так сделать? Ты уже можешь создавать дивы и уже можешь добавлять их в другие дивы - непонятно с чем из этого проблема

Comment: простите,я затупил.Уже понял как это решить